# Wrong emblem used for PDFs created by LibreOffice

Tags: files, linux-mint, pdf, libreoffice

If I create a test pdf file in a directory, by using something like

```
ls -al > testpdf.pdf
```

the file is shown in Caja 1.4.0 with an understandable emblem that is 'acrobat-like'.

If I create a LibreOffice document in Writer and export it to PDF in the same directory, its emblem is a grey 'sheet of text' which makes it very hard to spot.

How can I change the icon/emblem used by PDFs created by LibreOffice?

Can I just overwrite the file used somewhere in `/usr/shr/icons`? If so, will it be overwritten by the next LibreOffice update?

Comment: On Linux, a lot of file manager detect the file type not by extension but by looking at the content of the file. So if you create `.pdf` files with non-pdf content, you get usually other icons than for real pdf files. Usually, you can select in the options of a file which icon should be used for the corresponding file type.

Comment: Is that icon trademarked perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like an issue of the file manager not properly recognising the file type - almost as if it used the extension to infer it (which is rather obsolete imho). Does your pdf's name (the one exported from libreoffice) end with `.pdf`?

`/usr/share/icons` (basically everything under `/usr`, `/lib*`, `/etc`) is "system" owned and may be overwritten on package updates (with the exception of configuration files which are treated slightly differently).